# DirectoryServices filter and methods

Tags: powershell, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to get a list of all users in an OU/DC from AD.

This is what I came up with:

```
$erroractionpreference = "SilentlyContinue"
function Get-GroupMembers {
    $filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))"
    $objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
    $objSearcher.Filter = $filter
    $colResults = $objSearcher.FindAll()

        foreach ($member in $colResults) { 
            $member
        }
}
get-GroupMembers
```

If I change the filter to

```
    $filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)("OU=Admin Accounts,DC=admin"))
```

Nothing returns. Why is this?
I would also like to display certain values (if the accounts is active or disabled etc) but if I pipe `$member` to `gm`, I get nothing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Be carefull @TiZon your are Mixing three things. Ajk explain you how to use ADSI object with DirectorySearcher, this is working till PowerShell V1.0. USlackr is using Cmdlets comming from ActiveDirectory module available on Seven and W2K8R2 on PowerShell V2.0. Christian is using Cmdlet comming from a Qest package available since PowerShell V1.0. All 3 solutions works but just don't mix the three

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to search a specific OU, you can set it as the root of your searcher object:

```
$objOU = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=Admin Accounts,DC=admin")
$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$objSearcher.SearchRoot = $objOU
```

You can also control the scope of your search. Here are the two most relevant options for you:

```
# Option 1: Return only users in the 'Admin Accounts' OU
$objSearcher.SearchScope = "OneLevel"

# Option 2: Return users in the 'Admin Accounts' OU or any level beneath it
$objSearcher.SearchScope = "SubTree"
```

Unless you override the search root and scope, you'll get the default of performing a SubTree search against the root of your current domain. You can find more detailed information in this TechNet article:

- [Searching Active Directory with Powershell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730967.aspx)

**Edit:** As uSlackr noted, your DC component does look fishy. I left it intact for my example, but an incomplete/malformed base object name will botch your search regardless of the method you use.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I combined your answer with the help from @uSlackr

Answer (score 5):

The DC component is not complete.  It should look something like this:

```
 $filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)("OU=Admin Accounts,DC=myco,dc=com"))
```

but the dc=admin,dc=com should translate from the AD domainname in this example "admin.com" which doesn't seem right

This is much easier with the Microsoft AD cmdlets.

```
get-aduser -filter * -searchbase "ou=test,dc=mycom,dc=com"
```

Information on downloading and using the cmdlets is available on [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378937%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I combined your answer with the help from @ajk

Answer (score 1):

You can try use  the Quest ActiveRolesManagement Shell for ActiveDirectory downloadable from here:

http://www.quest.com/downloads/

The package is freeware and is the more accurate cmdlets for Active Directory management from powershell.